# setText() doesn't work

Tags: java, settext

I have this fxml part `<Text fx:id="username" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="1"/>`. When I want to set the username text, it doesn't work. I set it as follow:

```
@FXML
private Text username;
@FXML
protected void goToMyProfileButton(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    [...]
    username.setText("MyUsername");
    // username.setText(primaryUser.getText()); <- the real usage
}
```

Simply, the place where the text must be displayed is empty. I made the same thing in another scene and it worked corectly. But now, I get these errors:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$355(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$149(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at fxmlexample.Buton.goToMyProfileButton(Buton.java:194)
    ... 58 more
```

The `FXML` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.net.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>

<GridPane fx:controller="fxmlexample.Buton" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
    alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10" styleClass="root">
    <padding>
        <Insets top="25" right="25" bottom="10" left="25" />
    </padding>

    <Label fx:id="text" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
        GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0"
        text="Bun venit," />

    <Text fx:id="username" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="1"/>

    <Text fx:id="name" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1"/>

    <HBox spacing="10" alignment="bottom_center" GridPane.columnIndex="0"
        GridPane.rowIndex="2">
        <Button text="Inapoi"
            alignment="bottom_center" onAction="#backToLoggedButton" />
    </HBox>

    <HBox spacing="10" alignment="bottom_center" GridPane.columnIndex="1"
        GridPane.rowIndex="2">
        <Button text="Logout"
            alignment="bottom_center" onAction="#backToLoginButton" />
    </HBox>

    <stylesheets>
        <URL value="@application.css" />
    </stylesheets>

</GridPane>
```

goToMyProfileButton function:

```
@FXML
    protected void goToMyProfileButton(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../application/myprofile.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, SCENE_WIDTH, SCENE_HEIGHT);
        Stage stage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Profilul meu");
        stage.show();
        username.setText("MyUsername");
    }
```

Comment: Which one actually throws this exception: `username.setText("MyUsername")` or `username.setText(primaryUser.getText())` ?

Comment: Both of them throws the exception.

Comment: Can you post the corresponding `fxml` file?

Comment: Sure, the code is below.

Comment: Please post the code as part of your question instead of as an answer. Hit [edit] to the bottom left of your question.

Comment: Where is this action `goToMyProfileButton` in the `fxml` file? I cannot see it. Are you sure you posted the right code? Can you post the controller code?

Comment: The controller code has 200+ lines, it contains all my buttons actions. The part that throws the exception is in my question.

Comment: OK, so where is `goToMyProfileButton` ? Maybe you messed with `fxml` files and you posted here wrong `fxml` file.

Comment: I post it in my quiestion.

Comment: Well, but you annotated `goToMyProfileButton` with `@FXML`.

Comment: Sure. I have ~10 methods in controller code and all work corectly. I have only one `FXML` file. The problem is at `username.setText();`

Comment: OK, so why did you annotate this with `@FXML`? Why do you throw `IOException` from this method (is it because `FMLLoader.load` throws this exception?) ?.

Comment: Yes, the `IOException` was added by Eclipse beacause of `FXMLLoader.load`

Comment: Well, Eclipse added this because something must be done with this checked exception. But it is you who must decide how to handle this exception, in other words you must know what you're doing. Ok, let's try another approach. You have a method `goToMyProfileButton` which is an action bound to what? What triggers this action?

Comment: I simply hit a `HBox` button and the scene changes.

Comment: You have two buttons in `HBox` containers with the following actions: `backToLoggedButton` and `backToLoginButton`. None of them is `goToMyProfileButton` action. So? Remove this annotation from this action.